# regex maximum length not including special characters

Tags: regex, regex-group

Let's say I want to match 4 numbers, but between them I can have white spaces and dashes.

Syntax for allowing max 4 numbers.

```
([0-9]){4}
```

How to make it ignore white spaces and dashes?

Comment: Your could use `^[\s-]*(?:\d[\s*-]*){4}$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression.

```
^[\s-]*(?:\d[\s-]*){4}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RAbukh/1/)

Comment: That is very nice of you!
I checked your answer, and it indeed works well, even better than what I tried out.

For my needs, even shorter regex is okay: "(\d[\s*-]*){4}"

Comment: You were right, there is a mistake! :D in the second [ ] brackets the * after \s shouldn't be there :D

Comment: The `*` you refer to is there so that the string `-  3 --- 12---4- -` (the second example at my link) will be found valid (no spaces between `1` and `2`). Note that in the question you said, "...but between them I *can* have white spaces and dashes." (emphasis mine)

Comment: I'm not talking about * after the second square brackets. I am talking about " * " inside second square brackets. It does not interfere with second example, it only makes regex with character "*" inside of them valid.

    [\s * -] <- * is not necessary

Comment: Kaspazza, I stand corrected. Thanks for the catch. Clearly there's no point in matchin `'*'`. See what I mean about giving time to catch errors? :D to you also.